# Change color from ng-repeat first item

Tags: angularjs

I have a strings array in my controller that I iterates with ng-repeat in my view. I want the first element of the array with other color. How can I do this?

```
<div ng-repeat="lang in vm.language">
        {{lang}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$first` in your loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="lang in vm.language">
    <span ng-class="{'some-css-class': $first}">{{lang}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-class directive with $first in your ng-repeat loop

```
 <div ng-repeat="lang in vm.language">
      <span ng-class="{first-element: $first}">{{lang}}</span>
 </div>
```

And your css class may look like this

```
  .first-element{
      color: #CC0097;
  }
```

Hope this will help you !!